# javascript - Global variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can a global variable be declared and set with a value in one js file be referenced in another js file, no matter how many times?

Apart from html files, can angular.js be used in a velocity macro file?

Comment: Yes, as long as any other javascript files are instantiated after the javascript file that defines the global variable.

Comment: @DanielShillcock you should post it as an answer before it gets closed lol

Comment: Hi daniel...consider i have a js file which appears only at the time of login..i create a global variable in that file..While logging out..i call a different js and try to use that global variable here...will it work?

Comment: Then that global variable is available to all scripts loaded after it on the login page only.

Comment: ok the global variable will be available in all the scripts that is loaded after the login page script,,,right David Barker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a global variable is defined in one script, it will be available to all other scripts in the page once it has been defined by the original script.  Global is global - it is available in all your Javascript in that page.

But, any Javascript variable only lasts for the duration of the current page.  As soon as you load another page, all global variables from the previous page disappear and an entirely new Javascript context is created and will be initialized by whatever scripts load in that new page.  No Javascript variables retain their value from one page to the next.

If you want to save some state such that the state is available across pages, then you must either store that state on the server (where it can be queried from the server), in a cookie (where a script can read it from the cookie) or in LocalStorage (where a script can read it from a LocalStorage key).

If your value was in a variable named `username`, then you could store and retrieve it like this:

```
// store the variable in localStorage
localStorage.setItem("user", username);


// and get the value from some other page
var username = localStorage.getItem("user");
```

Comment: @user2918673 - Just remember that when using LocalStorage, it is like a very simple database.  You can store something there and if you want to use it in a future page, you must read the value from LocalStorage to retrieve it.  Also, remember that data stored in LocalStorage is only available to the domain from which it was written (for security and privacy reasons).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use localStorage variable as:

```
<script>
        var v=localStorage.setItem("variable","value");
</script>
```

This can be said to be global variable which is accessed in any other file as:

```
<script>
        var val=localStorage.getItem("variable");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First i'll say what i have been said on the comments : 
that global variable will only be available for the javascript loaded in the same page.

Now if you're using angular, you should use a constant (ex : http://twofuckingdevelopers.com/2014/06/angularjs-best-practices-001-constants/, this is only true if you're doing single page application though.

You can use velocity to render your html/js files. However you should be really carefull about it because velocity has his own templating and angular too. Mixing two kind of templating is somewhat risky about maintenability and separation of concern. I suggest you to choose one that you will use at his fullest and use the other only when you really need and not using them for the same thing.